# jQuery :selected not not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm working on a form on a Drupal installation and am trying to use jQuery to check if a `select option` is selected, [jQuery( ":selected" )](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/). But when I try it the results show that everything is selected.

I've tried using both `.filter(":selected")` and just `:selected` but I get the same results with both.

Below is my code, I also set up a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cbe9dhg2/) to help debug.

**The html is:**

```
<select>
    <option value="_none">Select All</option>
    <option value="225">Residential</option>
    <option value="224">Commercial</option>
</select>
```

**and my js is:**

```
jQuery( "select" ).change(function() {
    if (jQuery ('option[value="225"]').filter(":selected") ) {  // if residential is selected
        console.log('res is selected');
    } else {
        console.log('res is NOT selected');
    }

    if ( jQuery('option[value="224"]').filter(":selected") ) {  // if commercial is selected
        console.log('com is selected');
    } else {
        console.log('com is NOT selected');
    }

    if ( jQuery('option[value="224"]:selected')  || $('option[value="224"]:selected') ) {  // if residential or commercial are selected
        console.log('com or res is selected');
    } else {
        console.log('com or res are NOT selected');
    }
});
```

**the console is logging:**

```
res is selected
com is selected
com or res is selected
```

Answer (score 4):

A call to jQuery always returns an object, wich is always true.

You have to check the length or use `is`

```
if ( jQuery('option[value="225"]').is(":selected") )
```

In this case just checking the value of the select seems easier

```
jQuery( "select" ).change(function() {

    switch(this.value) {
        case "255" : // do stuff
        break;

        case "224" : // do stuff
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

They are not boolean results. Check the length property of the filter result or change it to use `is`:

e.g.

```
    if (jQuery ('option[value="225"]:selected').length ) {  // if residential is selected
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/cbe9dhg2/1/

Comment: I don't think your jsfiddle is not working.  It's is giving 3 alerts

Comment: @Creed Bratton: It's *your* JSFiddle. I just fixed the checks. You wrote it with 3 alerts in the logic :)

Comment: sorry I'm blind! Did not see the word 'Not' in the alert.  Thanks for your help :)